# Does a ceiling fan switch make a ceiling fan slow with buzzing noise?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I replace my 6 year old ceiling fan because of really weak speed in any setting and of course the noise but apparently the new one makes the same i just check the voltage when the fan is on speed off but the switch on and show 120v but  when i put speed 1,2, or 3 shows 138v and if i turn the switch all the way to max will show 185  just to be clear electrical connections have been same since we move 6 years ago and ceiling fan was good until this month please if someone will give me an advice i will really appreciate thank you everyone

Comment: Is the wall switch a 1) normal switch 2) a fan speed control or 3) a conventional dimmer switch?  When you use speed 1,2,3 is that via the wall control or pull chains on the fan.  For that matter, specifically what are you touching your volt meter probes too, and is the fan running at that point?

Comment: What model is the new fan?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement: We'll need more info; please edit it into  your question.